# Issue connecting to AWS SQS using IAM Role with Boto 2.38

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sqs

I cannot authenticate to *AWS Simple Queue Service* (SQS) from an *EC2* instance using its associated *IAM Role* with ***Boto 2.38*** library (and *Python 3*).

I couldn't find anything specific on documentation about it, but as far as I could understand from examples and other questions around, it was supposed to work just opening a connection like this.

```
conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
queue = conn.get_queue('my_queue')
```

Instead, I get a *null* object from the *connect* method, unless I provide credentials on my environment, or explicitly to the method.

I'm pretty sure my role is ok, because it works for other services like *S3*, describing *EC2* tags, sending metrics to *CloudWatch*, etc, all transparently. My *SQS* policy is like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "SQSFullAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "sqs:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:<account_id>:<queue_name1>",
        "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:<account_id>:<queue_name2>"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In order to get rid of any suspicion about my policy, I even associated a *FullAdmin* policy to my role temporarily, without success.

I also verified that it won't work with *AWS CLI* as well (which, as far as I know, uses *Boto* as well). So, the only conclusion I could come up with is that this is a *Boto* issue with *SQS* client.

Would anyone have a different experience with it? I know that switching to *Boto 3* would probably solve it, but I don't consider doing it right now and if it is really a bug, I think it should be reported on git, anyway.

Thanks.

Comment: Try running AWSCLI with the ``--debug`` flag and post the output here.  From your description it sounds like boto and AWSCLI (which is not built on boto but on botocore) are just not finding the IAM role on your instance.

Comment: Solved! I won't paste the full output here, since it is too long. But there were 2 problems. 1) In my root user, which I was using to put a message with the CLI, there was a credentials file which was overriding iam-role, which seems to be last one Boto looks for to authenticate. I can clearly see the difference on debug mode after deleting it. 2) Regarding my application, there was a bug on it when verifying credentials from environment, and if it didn't exist it never made it to the next block, where I don't pass any credentials to the client. Thanks for you tip, it was clarifying to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself.

Boto's 2.38 SQS client **does** work with IAM Roles. I had a bug in my application.

As for AWS CLI, a credential file (*~/.aws/credentials*) was present in my local account, and being used instead of the instance's role, because the role is the last one to be looked up by the CLI.